# How can I not use nested lapply here?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

Checking to see if date formats match within the date variables of my data frame using this code:

```
df %>% 
  select(date_vars) %>%
  lapply(function(x) x[!is.na(x)]) %>%
  lapply(check_date_format) %>%
  lapply(all)
```

Everything works correctly but I was wondering if someone could tell me if there is an easier way to do this without continually nesting lapply.

Comment: you could try to use `purrr`, e.g. library(purrr)
`df %>% 
  select(date_vars) %>%
  map(~.x %>% check_date_format %>% all)`

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you want to find all valid dates within your data.frame.

Her is a way to subset your data.frame to only contain those with a valid date_vars

```
library(tidyverse)


df = data.frame(date_vars = c("2023-08-15", "4281-41-21", "", "1928-08-08"))

df %>% 
  mutate(date_vars = as.Date(date_vars)) %>% 
  subset(!is.na(date_vars))
```

If you want to have a logical vector of which are valid dates, you can do this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(is_valid_date = ifelse(!is.na(date_vars %>% 
                                         as.Date), TRUE, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can put everything into one single lapply like this:

```r
df %>% 
  select(date_vars) %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    {x[!is.na(x)]} %>%
    check_date_format() %>%
    all()
  })
```

Not sure if that applies to your specific case, though.